# Pushing up and pulling down a UIView

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I have been playing around with UIView animations and for this questions i do not have any code yet, because I do not know yet:-) In saying that I also cannot find it anywhere on the net so I hope forums can help now.

I have one full screen UIView (we make it blue to separate it easy) and I have another UIView which fills up about half starting from the top. (make it green). I want to be able to push that green UIView up with my finger and pull it back down again. The Green area has 2 positions it can be in and the event is triggered by "the pushing your finger into that direction event" - I gave it a name, because I cannot find any tutorials on how to do that. Does anyone have something that is useful to me with what I am asking??

I am still looking :-)

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html).

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/ehuynh/EHDragOutView.
I developed it for another app and decided to pull out the code into another project . Might be a good place to start

Comment: Great work. Is it possible to add UIButton inside the EHDragOutview?

Comment: should be no problem. As I remember it's just a UIView subclass